# Is WebRTC without createOffer/Answer possible on a local network?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Is it possible to establish a WebRTC connection between two browsers on a local area network without calling `createOffer/Answer` and instead by manually creating local and remote descriptions?

The browsers are not behind NAT with respect to each other and they have signaled their IP addresses somehow (say via a local HTTP server).

Would it be possible to do something in the spirit of:

```js
const myIp = '192.168.0.1'; 
const peerIp = '192.168.0.2';

const c = new RTCPeerConnection();
c.setLocalDescription(MAGIC_createLocalDescriptionFor(myIp));
c.setRemoteDescription(MAGIC_createRemoteDescriptionFor(peerIp));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! If you are using Chrome. Check out [offline-browser-communication](https://github.com/pion/offline-browser-communication)

You have three points of state you need to deal with.

- IP/Port. You can setup your network in a way that this is stable. Or attempt to do some guessing?
- ufrag/pwd. You can set this via SetLocalDescription so you can control these.
- DTLS Certificate. Use [GenerateCertificate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/generateCertificate) this means you will only have to signal it once.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the browser. The offer and answer contain properties such as ice-ufrag, ice-pwd, the DTLS fingerprints and the candidate ports etc that are not static.